# SharePoint SSRS integrated mode

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, reporting-services

I look after a SP Farm that runs SSRS integrated and every now and then some of the scheduled SSRS subscriptions fail to run (with an error message).

Recently I have seen scheduled subscription not triggering or even triggering in a complete different time where they were supposed to.

My question: what is responsible for triggering the SSRS subscriptions? Is a SP timer job? Or a SQL 'thing'?

Answer (score 0):

There's a SharePoint Timer Job:**SQL Server Reporting Services Service Job for SQL Server Reporting Service Application**.
However, report subscription info is stored in SSRS database tables: [Subscriptions], [ReportSchedule], and [Schedule]

**Further investigation** revealed that:

1. When a report's subscription is created, a SQL Server Agent Job is created 
   with the same id as the ScheduleID.

   **The Command in the SQL Job's step**

```
exec [ReportServerDBSP].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='987dd212-3328-4d77-a358-21644b4bf4d7' --SubscriptionID
```

2. The SQL agent's job runs as per the schedule and creates an entry in [Event] 
   table in the Report DB
3. In SharePoint, SQL Server Reporting Service Application's polling process 
   (w3wp.exe process) gets started by SharePoint Timer job, specifically by SSRS 
    Service Job for SSRS application and then it creates notifications and 
    processes and delivers the actual report.

Having said that, I now believe, reports get processed as per the SQL Agent job's schedule, not the SharePoint timer job's schedule.

Comment: That timer job runs every 5 min in my environment. However the subscriptions are triggered at any time (not necessarily in 5 min). 

E.g.: I have a subscription scheduled to run 12:03PM and the timer job runs at 12:00PM and 12:05PM - I still get the subscription run and delivered at 12:03PM